# How to access value of a particular post field in symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to access a particular field value when posted, similar to $_POST['title'] in core PHP. How can I achieve this in Symfony 2.8?

So far I have tried using

`$request->request->get('name')` --- returns all values from post.

`$request->request->all()` --- same returns all values.

`$request->request->get($form->get('name'))` -- again same..returns all values

If I pass something in get() it shows nulls, `eg:-` If I passed `$request->request->get('Title')` --- returns null.

I have attached the image for better understanding.

Returns All[image]

Returns Blank[image]

Controller[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
$request->query->get('Title');
// OR
$request->request->get('Title');
// OR
$request->get('Title');
```

You can also able to this with `Entity`:

```
$article = new Article();
$article->getTitle();
```

Full Information : https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object

Comment: I have already tried them, but they all return null. ( as shown in above Image )

Comment: Update anwser, please check, hope it will be helpful for you

Comment: I had already done it using the get() method, but nevertheless, thank you for answering. I will mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by storing it into a variable, like this

`$data = $request->request->get('form');`

//or

`$data = $request->request->all();`

and then accessing it through array keys. `$data['Title'];`